# What is the best options for tippecanoe to process line string features?

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl-js, tippecanoe

I have a GeoJSON file with a *FeatureCollection* (more than 300 000 features) of *LineStrings*. It is a road traffic records. I need to convert it to the MVT format using Tippecanoe. I'm trying to convert the GeoJSON with this params:

```
tippecanoe data.geojson -pf -pS -zg --detect-shared-borders -o data.mbtiles -f
```

Then I uploading it to Mapbox account as a tileset and use to render with Mapbox GL JS. And there is a problem - not all the features are visible. Moreover, if if will reconvert the GeoJSON file - then I will get a different result! So - what is the best options to use with tippecanoe to convert all the features (lineStrings) without oversimplification to use it with Mapbox GL JS?

P.S. One more thing which I noticed is that datasets uploaded with Mapbox Studio and then converted to tileset has some info like this: "*This layer contains mostly LineStrings*", but with my own tilesets converted with the tippecanoe I see a next message: "* No dominant geometry type*"

Comment: It's hard to answer in general. I have found that line features often process less well than points or polygons in Tippecanoe. I usually end up doing lots of trial and error with different command line settings.

Comment: Thank you @SteveBennettㄹ . Unfortunately, I converted one more file with only Points `tippecanoe  -o data.mbtiles data.geojson -pS -zg -r1 -pk -pf  -f` (with more than 300 000 points) and I see that not all the points were saved :( What options for Points do you use?

Comment: In one case, I use `-Z 7 -z 15 -B 11 -m 7 -pd -rf100000`. See https://github.com/stevage/vector-tile-scripts

Answer (score 0):

-ae will auto-increase the maxzoom if features are still being dropped at that zoom level. But when zoomed out it doesn't always look good depending on the type of features (e.g.: mising cadastre doesn't look good)...